# null value in column "logo_url" violates not-null constraint in django

Tags: python, django

I am trying to make an app that searches the logo of a website and gets the link of the image. Unfortunately, it gives me this error on some sites like "reddit.com" and the code is working fine on sites like "crossfitcut.com".
Why is the problem appearing and how can I eliminate it?

This is the code for the logo searcher:

```
BAD_WEBSITE = 'bad_website'

# if I eliminate this function the compiler doesn't give me an error
def validate_url(value):
    url_validator = URLValidator()
    value_1_invalid = False
    value_2_invalid = False
    try:
        url_validator(value)
    except:
        value_1_invalid = True

    if not value_1_invalid:
        return value

    value_2_url = "http://" + value

    try:
        url_validator(value_2_url)
    except:
        value_2_invalid = True

    if value_1_invalid and value_2_invalid:
        raise ValidationError("Invalid URL")

    return value_2_url

def get_logo(url):
    website = validate_url(url)
    try:
        result = requests.get(website, headers={
            'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/58.0.3029.110 Safari/537.36'
        }, timeout=30)
    except:
        return BAD_WEBSITE
    if result.status_code == 200:
        soup = BeautifulSoup(result.content, 'html.parser')
        logo = None
        try:
            for item in soup.select(re.compile('.*logo.*')):
                if item.name == 'img':
                    return item['src']
                else:
                    return item.find('img')['src']

        except:
            pass
        if not logo:
            stripped = website.strip('/')
            homes = ['/', 'index.php', 'index.html', 'home.html']
            urls = [website]
            for home in homes:
                urls.append(stripped + '/' + home.strip('/'))
                urls.append(home)
                urls.append('/' + home)

            for item in soup.find_all('a', href=True):
                if item['href'] in urls:
                    try:
                        return item.find('img')['src']
                    except:
                        pass

        if not logo:
            try:
                for item in soup.find_all('img'):
                    if 'logo' in str(item):
                        return item['src']
            except:
                pass
        return None
    else:
        return BAD_WEBSITE
```

views.py

```
class HomeView(View):
    def get(self, request):
        the_form = SubmitUrlForm()
        context = {
            "title": "Find Logo",
            "form": the_form
        }
        return render(request, 'home.html', context)

    def post(self, request):
        form = SubmitUrlForm(request.POST)
        context = {
            "title": "Find Logo",
            "form": form
        }
        template = 'home.html'
        if form.is_valid():
            new_url = form.cleaned_data.get('url')
            true_url = clean_url(new_url)

            get_logo_url = get_logo(true_url)
            true_tld = tld_of_url(true_url)

            obj, created = FindLogo.objects.get_or_create(url=true_url,logo_url=get_logo_url,tld=true_tld)
            context = {
                "object": obj,
                "created": created,
            }
            if created:
                template = 'success.html'
            else:
                template = 'exists.html'

        return render(request, template, context)

class LogoRedirectView(View):
    def get(self, request):
        obj = get_object_or_404(FindLogo)
        return HttpResponseRedirect(obj.url)
```

HTML file:

```
<div style=" align-text: center; width: 800px; margin: 0 auto;">
    <h1>Added to database</h1>
    <h2>Search Logo Function</h2>
    <img src="{{ object.logo_url }}">
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <form action="."> {% csrf_token %}
        <input type="submit" value="Find another Logo">
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: give a default url to the logo, which should be stored in the database if no logo is found, like no image available type of image url and then check for reddit.com

Comment: Thank you! I also had to add null=True, now it works as intended.